# HTML5 Video not working in Android

Tags: html5-video

I am building a little application to display a video for users and I am having a lot of issues with mobile devices.  It seems to work perfectly on desktop, and hit and miss on mobile.  It works on one iPhone, but not another and it definitely does not work on my android even when i navigate directly to the files.

Here is my code.

```
<video id="video1" width="600" controls="">
<source src="~/Content/Video/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="/Content/Video/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

its ripped right from the example from w3schools http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp  files and everything.  When I visit that site on the mobile device, it works, when hosted on my site it doesn't.

here is a screen shot of the android device, the player shows up but nothing i can do will play the video[image]

I am running windows server 2012, and the android device is Android 4.4.4; SM-N900V Build/KTU84P, Chrome 41.0.2272.96.

because these files and code are ripped directly from another source that seems to work the only thing I can think of is that something on the server is not set up correctly.

thanks!

Comment: Does the server have the correct mime types set up to handle the files?

Answer (score 0):

The  tag is only supported by modern browsers. The problem you are facing is with browsers running on the client mobile or desktop and not your servers.

See browser support to understand which versions are supported: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video

Comment: See the screenshot above, i am using chrome and it works on other sites, just not when I am hosting it.